# Debugging python application meant to be run from terminal

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, ide

I want to resolve bugs of a complex python application written by someone else. I would like to set up Visual Studio Code [VSC] and its debugger so that I can step through the code.

The python application is meant to be run from a linux terminal using arguments, not as python. For this reason I am not able to set up VSC appropriately, nor to run the application's commands in python. As an example I recreated the application using two files:

File1 myprog:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
def format():
    #print('  myprog > format: sys.argv=',sys.argv)
    import myprog   
    myprog.format_doc()

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        command = sys.argv[1] 
        if command == '--version':
            print('V1.0')
        elif command == 'format':
            eval(command+'()')
main()
```

File2 myprogr.py:

```
import os, sys
def format_doc():
    print('  myprog.py > format_doc: sys.argv=',sys.argv)
    print('  more complicated code I want to debug using several arguments')
```

When I run the application from terminal I see that the arguments are passed to File2 in sys.argv (I think as an effect of eval):

```
bash>./myprog format hello.txt --someoption
  myprog.py > format_doc: sys.argv= ['./myprog', 'format', 'hello.txt']
  more complicated code I want to debug using arguments
```

Can I set up VSC to run the above bash command and step into the python code?

Alternatively, can I run the methods in File2 from python so that I can easily debug it in VSC? As you can see I cannot add arguments using python because the python method accepts no input arguments:

```
>>> import myprog
>>> myprog.format_doc()
  myprog.py > format_doc: sys.argv= ['']
  more complicated code I want to debug using several arguments
>>> myprog.format_doc("hello.txt","--someoption","or_maybe_some_option")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: format_doc() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Have you considered using the [Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)?

Comment: I've never tried it, but how about: `sys.argv=["hello.txt" ... ]` then `myprog.format_doc()`

Comment: @quamrana yes, it is easy and it works

Comment: @quamrana In my real application I need to add the location of the script (in my example above File1): sys.argv=["/home/myusername/anaconda3/bin/the_real_application", "hello.txt", "--html_output=hello.html"]